# Draw annotation on Twilio Video Chat

Tags: twilio

I want to use twilio for Remote assistance. 
Where user can share camera feed and Technician can assist by drawing annotations on the screen.
similar to the demo video on https://www.twilio.com/video
I was able to get the Video Chat running on my iOS devices.
Can you please guide me how to make annotations on one device which will be shown on the other device.

Comment: @philnash ,like i said i have Video Chat running, i want to understand whether twilio provides in built support for annotations on the camera preview, if not then how can i use the existing socket connection of twilio , to may be pass the touches from one device to another. and recreate the annotations. There aren't any Delegate methods available for that.

Comment: Twilio Video does not provide support for annotating videos as part of the SDK. There is also no current support for using the WebRTC data channel to send that across. You need to provide your own websocket solution for this I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio Video does not provide support for annotating videos as part of the SDK. There is also no current support for using the WebRTC data channel to send that across. You need to provide your own websocket solution for this I'm afraid.

**Edit**

[Twilio Video does support the data channel now](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/10/programmable-video-launches-datatrack.html), under the Data Tracks API. You can see the documentation here:  https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/javascript-v1-using-the-datatrack-api.

You might also consider using [Twilio Sync](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sync) for something like this too.

Comment: can u describe more about the web-socket solution, how to get this where to search and so